# Help transcribing part of a YouTube Video

Tags: transcription

I came across this video in July 2013, and I've tried to understand some of what was being said, but because of my severe hearing loss and almost no captions, I wasn't able to make out all of the video. I was able to infer about 90 percent of what was said, though. Someone on Meta recommended that I reach out to ELL or English SE to ask transcript-related questions.

At around two or three minutes into the [video,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nap1QGt8tFo) he said something like *And when I poke her, you can thank me for something something because I do not breathe through my mouth or nose. I breathe tthrough... what's it called?*

I don't know what he meant by *and when I poke* Can somebody clarify on this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a more specific timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He is talking about the operation he had, and says:

> ..and when I woke up, I became different from everybody else in this room because I no longer breathe through my mouth or nose. I breathe through... what's it called? (Audience: "Stoma")

Answer (score -1):

he said do not poke fun at me because I'm here to educate you but tbh I don't think it's completely your hearing loss that made you not be able to understand that yt video it's kinda hard to hear